# Delete in bulk local git branches that contains a string

Tags: git, bash, terminal, grep, branch

Having some local git branches, let’s say for example:

```
…
Case001-FeatureA-doX
Case002-FeatureA-doX
Case001-FeatureB-doX
Case002-FeatureB-doX
…
```

How can I delete from the terminal those ones that contains “FeatureA” or “Case001”?

I guess it must to be something like `git branch -l | grep "FeatureA" …` but I do not know how continue.

**Update** with the solution that worked for me

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='git branch -d %(refname:short)' refs/heads/Case001-* | sh -x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git for-each-ref --format='git branch -d %(refname:short)' \
      refs/heads/*-FeatureA-dox refs/heads/Case001-*-dox \
| sh -x
```

Comment: Thanks @jthill, it almost worked. + git branch -d refs/heads/Case001-dox. error: branch 'refs/heads/Case001-dox' not found. The problem is that the branch it is called just "Case001-dox" but not "refs/heads/Case001-dox".

Comment: Should have used '%(refname:short)', then.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have git at work, but I think that git -d can take more than one branch so

```
git -d Case001*
```

could work. Otherwise

```
git branch --merged | grep "FeatureA" | xargs git branch -D
```

xargs being the key point. You can list your branch the way you want.